# "extension" or "relaxation" of last date?

Tags: word-choice

Sometimes, there are deadlines for events and sometimes they are extended. In case of such an event, is it correct to say "extension" of last date? But, how can a date itself be extended? I guess relaxed is a more appropriate word.

Please suggest..

Also, if "relax" is the proper word, then should it be -

> relaxation "of" last date?

Is "of" correct here?

Comment: Oh downvoter please explain why..

Comment: I don't know why the downvoter voted, but this sounds way too local to me. A date can't be literally extended (it is a point in time) but metonymically it can (the span of time to reach that point). So 'extended' is fine and better than 'relax'. Also 'relaxation of the due date' works, but 'relaxed the due date' (verb without preposition here.) Stick with 'extended' though.

Answer (score 1):

How can a date be relaxed either?

With deadlines, *relaxed* can be used, but *extended* is both reasonable and more common. Both mean the deadline was changed to a different date (the date itself was unaffected, and e.g. the 27th of February would remain the 27th of February).

With events like a show for which there were say showings from the 13th to the 20th that was then changed to run from the 13th to the 24th, we would not normally use *relaxed* (unlike a deadline, it doesn't ease anyone's workload to have this happen), but would use *extended*.

We might say the last date was extended, again this doesn't affect the date itself, but it affects the event; The event has a property that is it's last date, and that property was extended. This is someone would mean if they said "the last date was extended for another 3 days".

I'd consider "the run was extended" to be clearer though.

Comment: I think you've hit on the most important factor - the fact that the term _date_ isn't irrevocably tied in to a fixed position on the calendar: **date** 1  (dt)
n.
1.
a. Time stated in terms of the day, month, and year.
b. A statement of calendar time, as on a document.
[the above unalterable unless we rejig the calendar itself]
3.
a. A particular point or period of time at which something happened or existed, or is [']expected['] to happen. [and the latter subject to change, especially when that would be least convenient] (AHDEL in the main)

Answer (score 0):

Deadlines are *extended*. Rules are *relaxed*.

When saying that the deadline is extended, you are really indicating that the period between now and the due date is [extended](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/extend?showCookiePolicy=true).

> a.to make longer in time or space; prolong
>   b.to allow a period of time for the payment of (a loan, mortgage, etc.) beyond that originally set

You might say the strict requirement for submitting the papaer by Thursday has been [relaxed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/relax?showCookiePolicy=true)

> 2.to make less strict or severe; soften *to relax discipline*

Answer (score 0):

*Extend* has several meanings, so multiple usages are possible.

To extend something is to stretch it. In this case, it is the time that is allowed for some kind of activity that must take place prior to the event.

> The committee has extended the submission period for manuscripts by another week.
>
> Ticket sales have been extended through the week of July 1.

But *extend* can also mean to push something outward— for example, changing a date to a later date.

> They extended the registration deadline to November.
>
> The librarian extended the due date to the 12th.
>
> The cutoff for applications was extended to close-of-business on Tuesday.

In this sense, I wouldn't say it's strictly wrong to speak of a *date* by itself being extended, but I don't think this usage is typical among native speakers.

The phrase *dates extended* means that certain events that took place on certain days will now also take place on additional days (for example, a performer having additional shows), and should not be confused.

Due dates are not *relaxed*. To *relax* something is to make it less rigid or strict, so one can speak of the rule or requirement that something be completed by a certain date being relaxed, but not the date itself.

> The professor relaxed her term paper guidelines; they can now be turned in after the public holiday or by e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can push back the date of some event.

From the OED:

> 2005   *Hotdog* June 12/1   With Pixar's *Cars* pushed back to summer 2006 the road is wide open for the first big animovie out of the blocks this year.

or bring it forward.

From Cambridge Advanced learner's dictionary:

> They brought the date of the wedding forward so her cousins could attend.

So, you may write *the pushing back of the due date* as well as *the bringing forward of the delivery date*.