# Word for an additional period of time allowed for something

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idioms, business-language

I don't know what word, idiom or phrase to use if I want to say "I want to be allowed to use some specific offers for additional period of time."
For example I am allowed to use software for one month I want to use it for one more month---

thanks in advance

Comment: I would use "extension"; see this question and answers: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104192/extension-or-relaxation-of-last-date

Comment: @sumelic thanks for your quick reply. could you possibly tell whether this sentence is okay, If I write it on subject of an email 
For example:
"Netbeans needs to be extended"

Comment: For the subject of an email, I would write something like "Request for extension of Netbeans trial session" if it is a trial session of the software or "Request for extension of Netbeans service"

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extension) gives this as one of the definitions of **extension**:

> 5 :  an increase in length of time; specifically :  an increase in
>   time allowed under agreement or concession

I think this would be an appropriate word.